# Pandas: Add columns to DataFrame based off existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 pandas DataFrames that I am manipulating in Python, and I would like to combine them based on a certain column (col_1):

```
#df1
    col_1   col_2          
0       3       7            
1       4       8            
2       5       5    

#df2
  col_1    col_3 
0     4       78
1     5       89
```

and the output should look like this:

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   3       7       0
1   4       8       78
2   5       5       89
```

I'm not sure about how to go about this using 'best practices'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col_1': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}, 'col_2': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 5}})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col_1': {0: 4, 1: 5}, 'col_3': {0: 78, 1: 89}})
```

You can use merge:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='col_1',how='left').fillna(0)
Out[22]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      3      7    0.0
1      4      8   78.0
2      5      5   89.0
```

If you need col_3 as int (thanks to piRSquared for his suggestion):

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='col_1',how='left').fillna(0, downcast='infer')

Out[25]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      3      7      0
1      4      8     78
2      5      5     89
```

Comment: `downcast` parameter will do the trick... `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='col_1',how='left').fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: Or `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='col_1',how='left').fillna(0).astype(dict(col_3=int))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join` after using `set_index`.

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('col_1'), on='col_1').fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      3      7      0
1      4      8     78
2      5      5     89
```

Answer (score 2):

Mapping a series if often efficient for a single column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [3, 4, 5],
                    'col_2': [7, 8, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [4, 5],
                    'col_3': [78, 89]})

df1['col_3'] = df1['col_1'].map(df2.set_index('col_1')['col_3']).fillna(0)

#    col_1  col_2  col_3
# 0      3      7    0.0
# 1      4      8   78.0
# 2      5      5   89.0
```

Comment: Mind you, this works because unique values of `df1col_1` are a super set of values in `df2.col_2`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('col_1').combine_first(df2.set_index('col_1')).fillna(0).reset_index().astype(int)
Out[237]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      3      7      0
1      4      8     78
2      5      5     89
```